# What is the best way to transfer large amount of small files from 1 Windows Server to another over the internet?

Tags: windows, rsync, file-sharing

I'm trying to one way sync around 100,000 small files for a total of 2GB from a server located in my office to a web server. I'm using Syncrify with some success but the scheduling feature does not work. FTP also seems to be slower than I'd like. Checking for updates and pushing the changes files (around 10 a minute) on demand would be ideal.

Does anyone have a solution for this or a similar problem?

Comment: Tyler, I'm VTC'ing this as opinion based only because you are asking "What is the best way", which will vary based on the situation/setup/etc.  You are better off asking about your specific issue using Syncrify and how to correct the issues it is having.  That would be much more on-topic (as mfinni points out in his answer)

Comment: VTC'ing? What does that mean?

Comment: VTC = Vote To Close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows) or some app that uses it
- [DFS Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) if the systems reside on the same domain and the files are not open files
- [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) with a scheduled task - simple, free, Windows-native, [works pretty well](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851678.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

RSync is made for this - the app you named uses it. You should figure out why the scheduling isn't working; do you have support from the vendor?